# Can I use a Cat 5 cable with Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage, cables

I want to connect my circuits together, but the problem is that the distance they have from each other are longer than my jumper cables can reach. So I had the idea to use a Category 5 (Ethernet cable) to connect my circuits over longer distances. How long can I have the cable go before problems will arise, such as voltage drops?

The distance between my circuits are at maximum 1 meter apart. And there are several circuits branching out to distances. The longest circuit will have 9V, and the other, shorter ones will have 5V. I am very noob with electronics, so please tell if there is anything else I should be aware of.

EDIT:

The data i am transmitting through the short wires are serial data, and the longer cable is a DC output to a motor. So the longer one is constant on or off, and serial is... Well, serial (Tx / Rx).

Baudrate for the serial communication is 115200

Comment: To answer this correctly requires knowledge of what is being sent down the cables. At the moment it's a bit like you asking if your vehicle will fit under a low bridge but you don't state the vehicle height.

Comment: If your issue really is that your jumper wires are not long enough, you can buy/make longer jumpers.

Comment: @Andyaka Updated description in question :)

Comment: @Murphy If it only was that easy... I can't find such cables where I live.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transmitting high frequency signals (e.g. SPI), one meter may likely cause issues. If the signals are ~DC you won't have an issue. The resistance of a meter of 24 gauge copper wire is less than 0.1 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can technically, but with 1 meter of cabling your signal, if sent down a fast baud rate, can get lost in the interference. You can use things like RS422 transceivers to turn your single-ended fast signal into differential pairs that is more resistant to interference and crosstalk and send them down the same twisted pair in the Cat5e (or Cat6 since that is all I have) cable to minimize interference.

Since you are talking sending UART signal down the wires you can use this RJ-45 pinout that is compatible with normal Ethernet cables, after turning the UART pair into RS422 (single-chip thing):

- Uplink:

  1. `TX+`
  2. `TX-`
  3. `RX+`
  4. `GND`
  5. `GND`
  6. `RX-`
  7. `GND`
  8. `GND`
- Downlink:

  1. `RX+`
  2. `RX-`
  3. `TX+`
  4. `GND`
  5. `GND`
  6. `TX-`
  7. `GND`
  8. `GND`

You can use normal Ethernet cables for this - straight-through cable when connecting uplink and downlink port together, and crossover when connecting two of the same type.

Comment: Baudrate is 115200

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen I would still use the RS422 transceiver just to be safe. And Ethernet hardware compatibility means very reduced cost - you probably have one lying around somewhere right now.